# How to stop autocorrect from putting a space after it corrects a word

Tags: ios, auto-complete, autocorrect

If I type something like "Helko" and press the "Hello" button that shows up on the bar above my keyboard, it will add a space, leaving me with "Hello ".

If I wanted to type "Hello." then this is frustrating, because now I have to delete the space before adding the period.

As another example, say I wanted to send my friend just the word `Hello`, but instead I typed `Helko`. *Is there a single button I can press* to go from `Helko` to `Hello`? (Without an intermediate `Hello` ?)

Is there any way to stop the autocorrect bar from adding a space after I choose to correct a word?

Comment: actually, on ios, you can type the `.` and it will place it immediately after the autocorrected word, where the space  used to be

Answer (score 2):

If the autocorrect word is highlighted, then you can also accept it by just tapping Space. If you double-tap Space, it will accept **and** insert the stop, same as a regular word.

[image] [image]

After question edits: this also works if you type any punctuation, bracket, question mark etc.

Comment: I agree that this is the functionality. How do I get it to go from `Helko` to `Hello`? That's what I want. As another example, say I want to type `(Hello)` but end up typing `(Helko`. How do I go from `(Helko` to `(Hello)` without needing to delete a space?

Comment: I wish you'd asked the question to which you needed the answer; but it's the same. Any punctuation will apply the autocorrect, if it's highlighted.

Comment: This is also helpful but somehow I keep on finding bad examples lol XD I'll edit my question again because that still isn't quite what I'm looking for

Comment: I think I found a better example and description: 1 button press to go from `Helko` to `Hello`: is there any way to do that?

Comment: My issue is that if I press any punctuation, I have to delete that punctuation. And if I press the button to correct it, it adds a space punctuation, which I don't like.

Comment: if you don't want punctuation, don't add it. If you do, do. All your added examples work the same way. Add punctuation & you get punctuation.

Comment: But what if I want the correct word with no punctuation? Even tapping the button to correct the word adds an extra space that I don't want.

Comment: Please be clear on **exactly** what you do want. If you don't want a space & you don't want punctuation, what's left to choose from?

Comment: “Is there a single button I can press to go from `Helko` to `Hello`?” Right now current solutions require 1. Pressing punctuation and then 2. Deleting that punctuation. I’d like it in a single button press. (Also, I’m sorry that my question has been so unclear. Thank you for your help!)

Comment: No there isn't, but neither can I see the point. If you've finished a word then unless you're going to send immediately you're still going to need to type something after it, whether that's a space or punctuation. if you're going to type another letter then you haven't finished the word. If you're going to send immediately then who cares if there's an extra space at the end. I simply cannot see your use-case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119078/discussion-between-pro-q-and-tetsujin).

Comment: That's if you've enabled Auto-"." in Settings > General > Keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single button you can press to go from `Helko` to `Hello` (and not `Hello` ). However, if you press "Send" or anything that submits the text, it appears that your device will remove the trailing space before sending the data. (I haven't found any cases where it does not.)

Also, as [@theonlygusi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/150109/theonlygusti) mentions, if you type punctuation (period, comma, exclamation point, etc.) after the space, your device will also delete the space.